# Concatenate Result returned from SQL in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

My SQL Query returns results as follows:
I have two tables, Users and Category, where Category uses foreign key(**userID**) from the User table (**id**).

```
[ 
    { "userTime": "14:00",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Jack",
        "Category.id": 11,
        "Category.name": "Category1",
        "Category.userID": 1
    },
    {
        "userTime": "14:00",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Jack",
        "Category.id": 12,
        "Category.name": "Category2",
        "Category.userID": 1
    }   
]
```

But I want to display the result as follows:

```
        [
            {
                "userTime": "14:00",
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Jack",
                Category: [
                    {
                        id: 11,
                        name: "Category1",
                        userID: 1
                    },
                    {
                        id: 12,
                        name: "Category2",
                        userID: 1
                    }               
                ]
            }
        ]
```

I am using Tedious and Nodejs to query the SQL DB, how can the above result be achieved by using either nodejs or javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is using the function `Array.prototype.reduce`.

This approach uses a variable `group` to put the necessary attributes/keys to build the grouping key.

```js
var array = [{      "userTime": "14:00",      "id": 1,      "name": "Jack",      "Category.id": 11,      "Category.name": "Category1",      "Category.userID": 1    },    {      "userTime": "14:00",      "id": 1,      "name": "Jack",      "Category.id": 12,      "Category.name": "Category2",      "Category.userID": 1    }  ],
    group = ['id'],
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, c) => {
      var key = group.map(g => c[g]).join('|');
      (a[key] || (a[key] = {userTime: c.userTime, id: c.id, name: c.name, Category: []})).Category.push({id: c['Category.id'], name: c['Category.name'], userID: c.id});    
      return a;
    }, {}));
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I have not down-voted it, any ways thanks for your help :)